# Passing the array to method (using random numbers)

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a program piece by piece. I continue to receive compile errors. Can you look at my code to determine my issue?

So here, I am saying that `array` can store 1000 elements of the double type. Now I want to pass the array to my main method and place 1000 random numbers into the array. So I will create a new method.

```
public class Practice{
   public static void main(String[] args){
     double[]array=new double[1000];
   }
}
```

Here, I have created a new method named `passArray`. I am trying to say that for each array element at its respective index (based on the count) assign a random integer until we reach 1000.

```
  public static void passArray(double[]x){
    for(int counter=0; counter<x.length; counter++){
      x[counter]=(int)(Math.random()*1000);
  }
```

Okay, so now I want to print my results to determine if my code does what I want it to do. In my main method, I will use an enhanced for loop:

```
    for(double k: array)
      System.out.println(k);
  }//End of main Method
```

The problem I continue to encounter is a compile error. However, the output displays 999 values as a double value at random. What in the world am I  missing here?

Comment: what compile error is thrown?

Comment: Could you put complete code, because I try to look at code and assemble it. It works fine.

Comment: @Natalia  The compile error shown was "one or more projects were compiled with errors." I think I should not have placed so many things in the <default package>.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure about the compile error, but your int to double problem is at the start of your code.

You declared an array of type double:

```
double[] array = new double[1000];
```

You're trying to type cast your random values to type int, which the compiler should accept.

```
x[counter] = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
```

However since this is an array of type double, then you're storing the values as doubles. i.e. the values get cast back to double immediately. All that java is really doing is, changing from a double, eg. 567.97, to an int 567, and stroing it as a double again 567.0. Notice that it has now lost all its floating point information from being cast to an int. Or in geekier terms, the mantissa has been set to all 0's.

Either you will have to declare your array as type integer. Or cast back to int every time you access a value.

eg.

```
int[] array = new int[1000];

public static void passArray(int[] x) {
// code
}
```

or

```
System.out.println((int)k);
```

Edit: Are you getting a compiler error, or warning? There's a big difference. A warning will allow it to run, which your posts suggests is happening, an error will not compile, and thus not run. You may just be getting a warning about the type cast from int to double.

Comment: that's exactly what's happening. You're right, I think it's a warning and not an error because it allows it to run. I think I will use int instead of double.

Comment: That's probably the best option; unless you need them as doubles later, there's no need to be casting back and forth. It's just a waste of cycles...

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo ( remove the '}' from the for loop )

and you need to pass the array to the method to make it work.

This compiles and runs :

```
public class Practice{
   public static void main(String[] args){

     double[]array=new double[1000];
     // calling the method
     passArray(array);
     // print the array
     for(double k: array)
         System.out.println(k);
     //End of main Method
   }

   public static void passArray(double[]x){
        for(int counter=0; counter<x.length; counter++){
          // compiles ... but why cast to int if you have double[] ?
          x[counter]=(int)(Math.random()*1000);
      }
   }
}
```